# (Beginner Programmer) Need help: Linked Lists in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to go through a book and see which lines a character appears on (A total of 64 characters) and I have to use linked lists. The problem is that I'm very new to linked lists and I'm not very confident with them. Also, I'm not the best at pointers and I'm prone to slipping up with them.

Below I have added my current code which is giving the error on line 59: "error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector".

I've read through a few people's answers on questions similar and none of them helped.

If anyone can see where I'm going wrong(I'm sure it's more than one place) I would really appreciate it if you could help me out and if I'm not using the linked list correctly constructive criticism is welcomed as I really am lost at the whole linked list concept. And before anyone goes ripping into my code, I'm relatively new to programming and have been pretty teaching myself for a couple of months so I know it's far from perfect. Also, I fix it up to LOOK better when I have it working, if anyone has issues with its current state. Thanks in advance :)!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 struct Characters{

    char names[65][50]; //This is the names array

};

struct Charline{
   char name;
   int line[60000];
   struct Charline * next;
};


char NameFun(){

    int i=0, choice;
    struct Characters c;

    FILE *fp = NULL; 
    fp = fopen("MisNames.txt", "r"); 

    for(i=0; i<65; i++){
        fgets(c.names[i], sizeof(c.names[i]), fp); //Gets each name and stores it as an element of an array
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

int LineScan(){

    struct Characters c;
    typedef struct Charline l;

    l *curr, *head;

    int i, j;
    int k=0;
    char string[300];

    FILE *fp = NULL; 
    fp = fopen("MisNames.txt", "r"); 

    head = NULL;

    for(j=0; j<=65; j++){

        curr = (l *)malloc(sizeof(l));
        curr->name[j] = c.names[j];
        curr->next  = head;
        head = curr;
        for(i=1; i<=68116; i++){

            printf("BUG");
            fgets(string, 250, fp);
            printf("BUG");

            if(strstr(string, c.names[j])!=0){
                curr = (l *)malloc(sizeof(l));
                curr->line[k] = i;
                curr->next  = head;
                head = curr;
                printf("Line: %d\n");
                printf("5BUG");
                k++;
            }

            else{
                continue;
            }


        }
    }



}


int main(){
    NameFun();
    LineScan();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the question is a bit broad. From what I can tell it could be rephrased as "I'm new to coding. I'm getting some compilation errors. Also, my code doesn't work. I'm new though, please help!"

Try tackling each of your issues separately. Focusing on one thing can make it a lot less overwhelming. Start with the compilation issues, you should hopefully be able to get through them with some more elbow grease. You may not understand the terminology entirely, but it should at least look "off". For instance, what makes you think that `c.names[j]` is the same type as `dude`?

Comment: @roliu Thanks, that got rid of the warning. I was just trying little things to get it working and looking at it I see where I went wrong in that part, I've update the code above now, no longer showing the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to start from [here](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf). I remember starting up with it when I wanted to learn about Linked Lists and it helps me a lot.